# Bind int to checkbox

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, checkbox, boolean, int

In my web site I have a bunch of checkboxes but unfortunately, ASP evaluates true as 1. The database I'm working with requires true to evaluate to -1.

How can I convert checkbox.checked to -1 and bind that? So far in my aspx source code I have:

```
asp:Checkbox ID="AFCanInstCheckbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckboxValue"
```

I realize that I need some sort of code behind that evaluates checkbox.checked to either 0/-1 and binds that int value. Can anybody suggest anything? I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it depends upon how you are passing your data beyond your presentation layer. Do you have a data-access layer (DAL)?

If you are doing in-line SQL in the code-behind on the click event handler, then you just need to check setup an `int` variable and set its value, like this:

```
int isChecked = 0; // Assume false
isChecked = AFCanInstCheckbox.Checked;

// Now in your SQL logic just use the value of isChecked to pass to database
```

If you are building a domain object (read: class) to pass to a data-access layer, then you can do it like this:

```
public class AFDomainObject
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

var theAFDomainObject = new AFDomainObject();
theAFDomainObject.IsSelected = AFCanInstCheckbox.Checked;

// Call DAL to do something
DAL.DoSomething(theAFDomainObject);
```